# Intern Turned Full Time, Time Obligation Considered Job Hopping?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-hopping

I am a recent college graduate of less than 1 year. For 3 years during my schooling I was employed by a company as an intern during the summer and winter breaks. The company would provide aide while in school and I am in turn contractually obligated to work full time with the company for X amount of time, where X is less than 1 year.

On my resume I note both the intern and permanent positions as separate because the conversion between the two was a promotion.

Since I will have been at my permanent position less than a year, would it be considered job hopping to potential employers if I leave this position after the time obligation expires?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the nature of the work you do has changed significantly with your promotion, it would seem odd to have two entries in your resume for the same company without a gap of time. Most people expect that promotions are a part of working for a company, and don't need to see it broken out into two jobs.

You should consider providing a single entry in your work history and in your description indicate that some of the time was as an intern and includes a promotion to full time. Having a single entry with nearly 4 years (in a couple of capacities and showing career progression) has a good chance of being seen in a very positive light.

It's unlikely that anyone would consider it job hopping either way you organize it. But it is more conventional to list the company once and describe your multiple roles within it.

Comment: Thank you! The work has not changed too significantly so I believe that this approach would be useful.